# Project release history file

Tags: github, version, history

I have an opensource project hosted on the GitHub.
After each release of my damn project I want to write out new features and bug fixes list to some file like **History.md**. It will look like:

```
=== Version 0.0.1 2012-12-21

Version with a new awesome bugs has been released

* [added] New feature
* [fixed] Some bug fixed
```

But I hesitate. May be I wrong? I don't know, so I ask. Is there are any guidlines/rules/suggestions/good expirience/anything else about how to format history changes? Or maybe change list should not be a single file?

Or more generally: what is the best way to track version changes (in a human readable format, of course) for Github (or any others hostings) projects and incapsulete it into the project itself in more pleasant way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publish a project release (binary/source packages) on Github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916492/publish-a-project-release-binary-source-packages-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

Github has issues with milestones.

If you link releases with milestones, **all** changes with tickets, then: all *closed tickets in milestone* will form human-readable changelog